# How to preserve "this" within Typescript Mocha test hooks

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js

In the below example, `token.test.ts` loads a test fixture into `this.token` within a `beforeEach`, to be reused within the hooks in `token.behavior.ts`.

```
// token.test.ts
import { shouldBehaveLikeToken } from './token.behavior';

describe("TokenTest", function () {
  beforeEach('reload token fixture', async function () {
    ({ token: this.token }) = await loadFixture();
  });

  shouldBehaveLikeToken();
  // More behavioral test suites
});
```

```
// token.behavior.ts
export function shouldBehaveLikeToken(): void {
  describe('balanceOf', function () {
    it('returns the correct balance', async function() {
      expect(await this.token.balanceOf(ADDRESS).to.equal(2)); // WORKS!
    });

  });

  function balanceOf() {
    return this.token.balanceOf(ADDRESS); // DOES NOT COMPILE WITH THIS FUNCTION!
  }
  
}
```

Regardless of how deeply nested assertions on `this.token` are, I am able to access `this.token` within Mocha hooks (`describe()` / `it()`) just fine.

However, if I create a helper function that uses `this.token` for making tests more composable within the test suite, I get the errors that `'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation` and `An outer value of 'this' is shadowed by this container`. This happens regardless of whether it is an arrow function or not, and regardless of where the function is defined.

Can someone explain what's going on? How can I make a helper function that uses the preserved `this` from the `beforeEach` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your external function `balanceOf` is requiring the `this` context to be that of `Mocha.Context` which is only available inside of a Mocha test. You must specify the `this` type of your `balanceOf` function, then bind the function to the `Mocha.Context` context explicitly like so:

```js
export function shouldBehaveLikeToken(): void {
  describe('balanceOf', function () {
    it('returns the correct balance', async function() {
      // It is only within this callback that your `this` context is `Mocha.Context`.
      // The context will not carry over outside of the callback.

      expect(await balanceOf.bind(this)().to.equal(2)); // Bind the function here.
    });
  });

  function balanceOf(this: Mocha.Context) { // explicit `this` type here.
    return this.token.balanceOf(ADDRESS);
  }
}
```

The reason why your first `balanceOf` function cannot correctly type `this` is because all function declarations (functions created with the `function` keyword) will bind either `window` or `global` by default, or to `undefined` if you're in strict mode. You can read more about how functions bind their `this` context [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#function_context).

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way of binding `Mocha.Context` to all subfunctions without having to explicitly bind for each function?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but you can save some effort by writing your functions inside of the Mocha test callback using arrow functions, e.g. `const balanceOf = () => { /* ... */ }` or as a normal function declaration with a dangling call to `bind`, e.g. `function balanceOf(this: Mocha.Context) { /* ... */ }.bind(this)`. You must be within the Mocha test callback though. If the function is declared outside then you'll have to bind explicitly like in the original answer.